# Excel vba - saving users current autocomplete setting as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for vba code which saves the users current autocomplete setting as I turn autocomplete off but then want to restore users individual setting. So if the user already had autocomplete turned off I don't want to turn it back on for them.

I want to make sure autocomplete is off while they are using my spreadsheet only. So original setting should be reverted to at end and can't assume everyone has autocomplete turned on as default.

How can I find that setting on the users computer and save it so I can restore the individual users setting before they close my workbook?

Thanks

Comment: How are you disabling autocomplete currently?

Answer (score 3):

First create two global, public Boolean variables to hold the AutoComplete status:

```
Public Boo1 As Boolean
Public Boo2 As Boolean
```

at the top of any standard module.  Then when your workbook gets opened *(Open Event macro)*, save the user's state:

```
With Application
    Boo1 = .EnableAutoComplete
    Boo2 = .DisplayInsertOptions
End With
```

Then in your Close Event macro, restore the user's state:

```
With Application
    .EnableAutoComplete = Boo1
    .DisplayInsertOptions = Boo2
End With
```

**NOTE(s):**

1. the Macro Recorder is a good tool to locate the proper Application setting
2. this can easily be extended to any Application setting

Comment: ..and there i learned something new. Nice. Does this only apply to the workbook with the code, or to all open workbooks?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i think the variables will get emptied once any macro returns an error.

Comment: @horst I am not sure of this